# Can I use "trickle" and "pour" for data streaming?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

Is this sentence OK if I want to say that the sensors collect the information slowly then send them to the phone quickly? These are new words for me, and I wanted to use them in a sentence.

> The information trickle to the sensors then pours to the phone.

Can I use "trickle" and "pour" for data streaming or just for people?

Comment: It might help if you [edit] your question to explain a little more why you feel like you couldn't use "trickle" and "pour" for data streaming so that folks don't get confused and think you are asking for proof reading.

Comment: These are new words for me, so I just want to put them in a sentence, so is the sentence ok or it stupid lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *water* metaphors, "stream", "trickle", and "pour" can work fine together, as long as you set up the metaphor correctly.  *To trickle* suggests a slow stream of water of minimal volume, while *to pour* suggests a much larger stream and volume.

> The rain **trickled** from the roof of the house in a slow, steady stream.
>
> The rain **poured** from the roof of the house, washing away all the debris that had accumulated in the gutters.

You are on the right track, but your metaphor is inelegant.  Sensors *collect* data, much like rain gutter, but they do not *store* data.  You need some kind of storage device for that, in the same way you would need a barrel to store up water.  Since you don't mention the storage device, it makes the reader question what you mean.

You should also consider that *pour* is commonly a *transitive* verb, meaning there is some *actor* who intentionally pours the water from one place to another.  For example:

> He **poured** her a cup of lemonade.

You would *not* say

> He **trickled** her a cup of lemonade.

If the data *pours* into the phone, then what is the mechanism that decides when this happens?  It makes more sense to say it *is poured* implying some (unspecified) actor.

> The water **trickles** through the gutters into the rain barrel, where at regular intervals it **is poured** into the cistern.

Lastly, you should consider common idiom.  You may have heard of "data dumps".  "To dump" is the common idiom to describe moving large quantities of data.  It doesn't really continue the water metaphor, but, since you *can* "dump" water, it doesn't break it either.

> The data **trickles** into the sensors and is stored in internal memory.  From there, at regular intervals, it **is dumped** to the phone.

(Edit) as Lambie's comment mentions, there is a time and place for metaphor, usually with creative writing.  When writing product documentation, it's better to be matter-of-fact.

> The sensors **receive small amounts of data over time** which is stored (somewhere).  (A monitoring process) then **dumps** this data to the phone (when certain criteria are met).

Metaphor would be fine in an article *about* the software.  Still, as I first said, you have to properly set up the metaphor.:

> The developers explain that the sensors **get a constant trickle** of data from hundreds of sources. Once certain criteria are met, this entire **pool** of data **is poured** into the end-users' phone for analysis.